# Where's the mean center of the contiguous US population?

Tags: cartography, coordinates

I can find 1790 to 2010 and an estimate for 2014 but Alaska and Hawaii are included after they became states and I wonder what it is without those states' extreme distances skewing the average. I don't know how to code, sorry. One link in the answer appears to have the answer (with a better method) for 2000. As Alaska and Hawaii's population isn't growing way faster than average anymore, I guess eyeballing 15 more years of drift from there is somewhat of an answer.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: While you can use GIS to answer this question, the question itself isn't about GIS, or how to acquire the data and software to answer the question with GIS, or about the procedures to obtain the answer using GIS.  I'm therefore voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Why is there no geography stack exchange? It seems like you'd have that first before you stated a GIS forum.

Comment: To understand why there is no Geography Stack Exchange, visit [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and type in "geography".  I think you will see that there is no current proposal - [there was once but it seems to have failed](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/10856/all-the-social-sciences-in-one-site).  To a geographer, GIS may seem like a subset of geography, but I think to most GIS practitioners it is a subset of information systems.  Also note that Stack Exchange is quite different from a discussion forum: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115

Answer (score 1):

i believe this may be an answer

https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/centersofpop/animatedmean2010.html
http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0311/population-drift.html

plus this is a really interesting article on the math behind finding the mean center - http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-population-center

long story short:  somewhere in Missouri

Comment: That is as of 2010, a lot of population has shifted since then, it may not be too accurate anymore. But good find! Its a step in the right direction.

Comment: census data is only taken every 10 years so 2010 is the most up to date information you will be able to get that is official census data.

Comment: I agree, it does not represent 2015 to the same accuracy as 2010, that is just something to be aware of.